# Convertor to change class name dynamically

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 in my application I use advanced drop down menu to show student name .My problem is if the same advanced dropdown option is used for professor,staff and department details. Now I use separate class for each converter just modification in

```
**Object value1 =resolver.getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "Student");
Student service = (Student) value1;**
```

line. 
My doubt is how to replace the class name to use it dynamically for all the convertors?

**xhtml**

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{Student.studentName}" var="bean"
   converter="StudentConvertor" >
<f:selectItems value="#{Student.studentNameList}" var="stuVar"    
   itemLabel="#{stuVar.studName}" itemValue="#{stuVar}"/>
<p:column>
<h:outputText value="#{bean.studName}"/>
</p:column>
<p:ajax event="change" update="studentPanel" 
   listener="#{Student.studentChangeAction}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

**Java**

```
public class StudentConvertor implements Converter
{

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
    {
        if ((value != null) && (value.trim().length() > 0))
        {
            try
            {
                FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                ELResolver resolver = facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver();
                Object value1 = resolver.getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "Student");
                Student service = (Student) value1;

                if (service != null)
                {
                    for (Integer studentId : service.getStudentNameList())
                    {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(value) == studentId)
                        {
                            return studentId;
                }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid value."));
            }
        }



        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            return String.valueOf(((String) value).getStudentId());
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the same information for all three classes, let's say Id and Name, you could try using inheritance:

```
public class Item{
    private Integer Id;
    private String name;
    //get + set for both
}
public class Student extends Item{}
public class Staff Item{}
public class Department extends Item{}
```

then change your service methods to:

```
public List<Item> getStudentList();
public List<Item> getStaffList();
public List<Item> getDepartmentList();
```

and finally, in your xhtml:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{Student.studentNameList}" var="item"    
   itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.id}"/>
<f:selectItems value="#{Staff.staffNameList}" var="item"    
   itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.id}"/>
<f:selectItems value="#{Department.departmentNameList}" var="item"    
   itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.id}"/>
```